# Gradle not executing my task

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have a task that is supposed to run a shell script. In Gradle, I have defined the following:

```
defaultTasks 'renaming'
... some other stuff goes here ...
task renaming(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', 'src/main/bin/rename.sh'
}
```

I have the shell script under my module in src/main/bin/
However, it is not getting run (for test purposes, the shell creates a directory called "asfasf"). How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried with full path like /Users/you/AndroidStudioProjects/yourProject/app/src/main/bin/rename.sh?

Comment: The project is to be compiled on different machines, so I'm not sure how to get the full path in that case.

Comment: Did you try to run the script manually ? Maybe there are errors in it

Comment: @minas The script contains only: mkdir -p "asfasf"

Answer (score 0):

As you give `sh` a relative path, it is resolved against the working directory of the `Exec` task. Either set the working directory for the `Exec` task or use `file('src/main/bin/rename.sh')` as second argument to `commandLine`.

Comment: Using commandLine 'sh', file('src/main/build/rename.sh') still does nothing.

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? It is not executed? It is said to be UP-TO-DATE? It produces an error? What? And what is your exact command you are running? Does adding `-i` or if not `-d` add more information that helps you see your error? If not, add the output of `-i` to your question.

Comment: "Nothing" as in compiles fine but doesn't seem to run the script at all. The shell script runs only this command: mkdir -p "asfasf". Running the script from the terminal works fine, so I assume the way I'm declaring the task in Gradle is wrong or it's just not picking up the correct path to it.

Comment: You left out half of my questions from my last comment